# mysql workbench ssh custo command

Tags: mysql, ssh, workbench

I'm trying to configure a new connection through SSH tunnel.

But on the server, the command mysql does not exists. I have my own compilation called custo-mysql.

I mean, when I'm on the server, I use the following command :

```
$ custo-mysql -u root -pmypassword
```

How can I tell workbench to use custo-mysql and not mysql ?

Answer (score 0):

`mysql` (and your `custo-mysql`) is a client for the server. Workbench is a client as well, so it doesn't need to use that `custo-mysql` thing. It just connects to your server.

Basically, on your server you have a "mysqld" running: a mysql server. Your commans `custo-mysql` connects to that server as a sort of interface. `Workbench` has the exact same function, so it should work if your networking/tunneling etc is correct.

Answer (score 0):

As @Nanne already mentioned, you don't need the `mysql` client to connect to your MySQL server using Workbench.

I would just like to point out that **Workbench does use the mysql command line client** for importing databases in the Admin / Data Import/Restore section. Having said that, you'll certainly be OK without it for everything else.

Cheers,